# Unable to run test cases in parallel using TestNG

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below error in stack trace:

> org.session.openqa.selenium.remote.Sessionnotfound Exception;Session Id is null.Using webdriver after calling quit?

**Scenario:**

I am creating driver instance in `@BeforeTest` method. 
Executed two test cases in parallel using *TestNG* framework.

Additional Info @saifur
I have created a separate Base Class in which i have initialized driver instance.I am calling that instance in @BeforeClass and driver.quit() in @AfterClass.By providing two different classes in testng.xml i am trying to run.

Comment: Please provide more info. Such as how you instantiate the driver and using `@BeforeTest` etc.

Comment: i have updated info.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you probably also have a `@AfterTest` method that calls quit() after each test?  If so, maybe your intention is to share one browser instance between multiple tests?

One thing that I do is: generate multiple browser instances in the DataProvider and then pass the browser instance via the returned Object[][] as a argument to each test method.   Then, I have a `@AfterMethod`  that calls quit() on each driver instance after each method is called.   That way, the DataProvider engine handles the instance thread separation between tests.

Just a thought.  Hope it helps.